# Laravel not reading changes to .env file

Tags: php, laravel, phpdotenv

After upgrading to Laravel 5.2, none of my `.env` file values are being read. I followed the [upgrade instructions](http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade); none of my config files were changed except auth.php. They were all working fine in the previous version, 5.1.19

`.env` contains values such as

```
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=myuser
```

`config/database.php` contains

```
'mysql' => [
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
]
```

I get this error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Not pulling in my env config. This is affecting every single one of my config files, including third parties such as Bugsnag.

I also tried

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

**Update**

Trying `php artisan tinker`

```
>>> env('DB_DATABASE')
=> null
>>> getenv('DB_DATABASE')
=> false
>>> config('database.connections.mysql.database')
=> "forge"
>>> dd($_ENV)
[]
```

I have tried installing a fresh copy of Laravel 5.2. I only copied it into my `app` folder; no additional composer packages are included. I still have the same issue. Other Laravel 5.2 projects on the same server are working fine.

Comment: Are you sure the .env file is named only .env? Not .env.example?

Comment: Andrew are you editing the .env file by the forge interface or uploading it?

Comment: @JamesElliott yes it is `.env`

Comment: Or are you running this locally? If your running under artisan serve you need to restart it just in case that might be the case.

Comment: @MarkDavidson editing it through vi in the command line, and no it's on a full server

Comment: Are the permissions correct on the file and readable by the web server user?

Comment: @aynber yes, global read. I just tested changing owner to Apache just in case and that didn't help either

Comment: My `.env` file created by forge is `0664/-rw-rw-r--` and owned `forge:forge`

Comment: Do you use any custom functionality for env or config? For example custom environment detection, custom config merging etc?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek not that I can think of

Comment: Please try `dd(App::environment());` and tell us what is the output.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki That outputs "production", regardless of what I set it to in .env

Answer (score 236, accepted):

If any of your `.env` variables contains white space, make sure you wrap them in double-quotes. For example:

`SITE_NAME="My website"`

Don't forget to clear your cache before testing:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Yes It's working. After Changing any value in `.env` file run the `php artisan config:cache & php artisan config:clear` command. It will work.

Comment: For Laravel8 use the same. In my special case only the  "php artisan config:clear" was enough.

Comment: this helped me a lot.. I didnt know I should be running those config clears..

Answer (score 109):

From the official Laravel 5.2 Upgrade Notes:

> If you are using the `config:cache` command during deployment, you
>   **must** make sure that you are only calling the `env` function from within
>   your configuration files, and not from anywhere else in your
>   application.
>
> If you are calling `env` from within your application, it is strongly
>   recommended you add proper configuration values to your configuration
>   files and call `env` from that location instead, allowing you to convert
>   your `env` calls to `config` calls.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0

Comment: `php artisan config:cache` solved it for me - nothing else had helped. Not even `php artisan config:clear` - thanks!

Comment: Laravel 5.3 `php artisan config:clear` is the only thing that worked for me

Comment: Laravel 5.4 - deployed on a VPS: `php artisan config:clear` worked for me. I didn't do config:cache before so it seemed a bit weird that I had to clear the cache.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19986#issuecomment-314317348

Comment: make sure you're editing `.env` instead of `.env.example` file

Comment: make sure you don't call `config:cache` before creating .env file :)

Answer (score 67):

For me it has worked this in this order:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

And I've tried all the rests without luck.

Comment: I think this removes the bootstrap/cache/config.php then you are not caching the configuration, that fix the issue at least for me, but I do not think it will be the best.

Answer (score 47):

Wow. Good grief. It's because I had an env value with a space in it, not surrounded by quotes

This

```
SITE_NAME=My website
```

Changed to this

```
SITE_NAME="My website"
```

Fixed it. I think this had to do with Laravel 5.2 now upgrading [vlucas/phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) from 1.1.1 to 2.1.0

Comment: Same think - seems like spaces causes issues in `.env` under 5.2 where as in 5.1 it didn't.

Comment: And this is one of my (many) bugbears with Laravel: it has a habit of sometimes silently ignoring and accepting a variety of configuration and/or other types of errors, with no indication anything has gone wrong. Given, this may be a "feature" of `phpdotenv`, but Laravel still knows there's a `.env` file that needs to be included, and that it wasn't successful, but doesn't bother to tell anyone.

Comment: I've already wasted hours on something so silly. Thank you for stopping me waste more!

Answer (score 28):

I had a similar issue in my `config/services.php` and I solved using `config clear` and `optimize` commands:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: Note that `artisan optimize` builds a number of caches, including the config cache, as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 26):

You can solve the problem by the following recommendation

**Recommendation 1:**

You have to use the .env file through configuration files,  that means you are requrested to read the .env file from configuration files (such as /config/app.php or /config/database.php),  then you can use the configuration files from any location of your project.

**Recommendation 2:**   Set your env value within double quotation

```
 GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID="887557629-9h6n4ne.apps.googleusercontent.com"
 GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET="YT2ev2SpJt_Pa3dit60iFJ"
 GOOGLE_MAP="AIzaSyCK6RWwql0DucT7Sl43w9ma-k8qU"
```

**Recommendation 3:** Maintain the following command sequence after changing any configuration or env value.

```
 composer dump-autoload
 composer dump-autoload -o

 php artisan clear-compiled
 php artisan optimize

 php artisan route:clear
 php artisan view:clear

 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan config:cache
 php artisan config:clear
```

**Recommendation 4:**  When the syntax1 is not working then you can try another syntax2

```
   $val1 = env('VARIABLE_NAME');     // syntax1
   $val2 = getenv('VARIABLE_NAME');  // syntax2
   echo 'systax1 value is:'.$val1.' & systax2 value is:'.$val2;
```

**Recommendation 5:** When your number of users is **high/more** then you have to increase the related memory size in the **server configuration**.

**Recommendation 6:** Set a default probable value when you are reading .env variable.

```
 $googleClinetId=env("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID","889159-9h6n95f1e.apps.googleusercontent.com");
 $googleSecretId=env("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID","YT2evBCt_Pa3dit60iFJ");
 $googleMap=env("GOOGLE_MAP","AIzaSyCK6RUl0T7Sl43w9ma-k8qU");
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that it's a bad idea to add secrets to the code base (see recommendation 6).

Comment: This is not real client & secret id, I have given a draft information to make understand the solution finder.
Thanks @Sherlock

Comment: That's not what I meant. If you're passing secrets as a second parameter to the env() method, that means you're adding these secrets to your repository, thus breaking the best practice not to include .env values in the repository.

Comment: please be careful: recommendation 6 is not a good practice

Answer (score 12):

I missed this in the upgrade instructions:

> Add an env configuration option to your `app.php` configuration file that looks like the following:
>   `'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production')`

Adding this line got the local `.env` file to be read in correctly.

Comment: I guess I got the same error, since my app was Laravel 4, then upgraded to 5.0, then to 5.1, etc. Probably missed adding this value in my app.php. Thanks for saving me a lot of time. Here's an upvote!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue on local environment, I resolved by

1. php artisan config:clear
2. php artisan config:cache
3. and then cancelling php artisan serve command, and restart again.

Answer (score 7):

Same thing happens when :port is in your local .env

again the double quotes does the trick

```
APP_URL="http://localhost:8000"
```

and then

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 3):

Also additional to what @andrewtweber suggested make sure that you don't have spaces between the **KEY=** and the **value** unless it is between quotes

**.env** file e.g.:

```
...
SITE_NAME= My website
MAIL_PORT= 587
MAIL_FROM_NAME= websitename
...
```

to:

```
...
SITE_NAME="My website"
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_FROM_NAME=websitename
...
```

Answer (score 3):

if you did call config:cache during local development, you can undo this by deleting the bootstrap/cache/config.php file. and this is work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this. Reason was that apache(user www-data) could not read .env due to file permissions.
So i changed the file permissions to ensure that the server (apache) had read permissions to the file. Just that and boom, it was all working now!

**Update:**
How to do this varies, depending on who owns the .env file, but assuming it belongs to the Apache `www-data` group, you can do this:

```
sudo chmod g+r .env
```

Modify it depending on your permission structure.

Comment: `So i changed the file permissions to ensure that the server (apache) had read permissions to the file.` this is actually wrong approach. You should have fixed apaxhe config so it serves this particular site as owner that owns these files

Answer (score 3):

In my case laravel 5.7  `env('APP_URL')` not work but `config('app.url')` works. If I add new variable to `env` and to config - it not works - but after `php artisan config:cache` it start works.

Comment: If you are on development enviroment you shouldn't cache your config and routes. To remove all cache you can use: `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: @ZohaibHassan How to turn off cache for config and routes on dev environment?

Comment: Above command will turn off 1. routes cache, 2 config cache, 3. clear views 4. clear optimized files 5. clear cache if any

Comment: For config only you can use `php artisan config:clear` it will clear your config cache and will not generate again and when you go on production you can run `php artisan config:cache` to cache your configurations

Answer (score 3):

I know this is super old, but today I discovered another reason why my `.env` was not loaded:

- I had a (commited) `.env.local`
- I recently switched `APP_ENV` from `dev` to `local`

With L8 (and maybe before), what happens is that it tries to find `.env.<APP_ENV>` and if it finds it, uses it.

Fun fact: in my case, `.env.local` was a blue-print file with non-sensitive information and not meant to be directly used, but that's what happened.

Removing the `.env.local` led to Laravel looking for `.env` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem generating a new key using the command: `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: Warning: DON'T do this in a already deployed site. Otherwise all the already encrypted data will not be accessible. Read first the Laravel documentation regarding data encryption before attempting this in production environments.

Answer (score 1):

if you did call config:cache during local development, you can undo this by deleting the bootstrap/cache/config.php file. and this is work for me.

@Payal Pandav has given the comment above.

I want to tell a simple workaround. Just edit the config.php file in the bootstrap/cache/ folder. And change the credentials. This worked for me. Please don't delete this file since this may contain other crucial data in the production environment.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to restart my Supervisord jobs (i.e. my queue workers). After doing so, a new environment variable I had added to my .env file was successfully pulled into my application.

> Remember, queue workers, are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory. As a result, they will not notice changes in your code base after they have been started. So, during your deployment process, be sure to restart your queue workers. In addition, remember that any static state created or modified by your application will not be automatically reset between jobs.

Source: [Official Laravel Docs - Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

Answer (score 1):

If you've come here because you have multiple `.env.*` files and `php artisan config:cache` resulted in incorrect settings, it's because it (tried to) read the `.env` file and not the one specific to your environment.  Try this instead (where `CODE` corresponds to `.env.CODE`):

```
APP_ENV=CODE php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using VSCODE and it turned out my `.env` file was auto-dectected by the IDE as a shell script file and not an Ini which was causing me the issue. It's a rare occurrence, but I hope it will save someone time.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel coder. We can use config() to solve this problem

in file "config/app.php":

```
'same_url' => env('SAME_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

in your code base:

```
$sameURL = config('app.same_url').'/orders/';
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who run their php application in **Docker** it might help to run `config:clear` and then **restart the container**, so the worker processes restart as well (if they're configured to run inside the same container as the application)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering issues with Laravel Valet where php artisan does not reflect updated `.env` variable values, consider using a unique naming convention for your environment variables as a workaround.

For instance, instead of using the default DB_USERNAME, rename it to DATABASE_USERNAME or another distinctive name. The root cause of the issue, where php artisan tinker still displays outdated values even after executing the commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

is unclear. This workaround can help bypass the problem by ensuring your application references uniquely named environment variables, potentially avoiding conflicts or caching issues with commonly used names.

refer: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/env-not-reading-variables-sometimes

Answer (score -1):

I made the mistake by doing dd/die/dump in the `index.php` file. This causes the system to not regenerate the configs.

Just do dump in view files will do. The changes to `.env` file update instantly.

Answer (score -1):

I had some problems with this.
It seemed to be a file permission issue somewhere in the app - not the .env-file.

I had to
 - stop my docker
 - use chown to set owning-rights to my own user for the whole project
 - start docker again

This time it worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using sail environment right after you change your environment variable just restart a server, otherwise it's going to show the old value.

Answer (score -1):

In my case (Laravel 7.x) it happen because I had set environmental variable on server. To be precise in Docker container.
And because environments variables are higher priority than .env file, nothing changes during .env file edit.

Check if you set the env variable on the server:

```
echo $VAR_NAME
```

Answer (score -3):

Tried almost all of the above. Ended up doing

chmod 666 .env

which worked. This problem seems to keep cropping up on the app I inherited however, this most recent time was after adding a .env.testing. Running Laravel 5.8