# Laravel how to connect MySql?

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-ec2

I have EC2 instance with MySQL installed and I am trying to connect MySql to Laravel, but I keep getting an error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`.

What am I doing wrong?

**`.env`file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=LOGI
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=MY_PASSWORD
```

Comment: have you ran `php artisan config:cache`? can you enter your mysql with that username and password using phpmyadmin or terminal? what have you tried other than changing the .env?

Comment: @SérgioReis Oh god. you saved my day. thank you so much. you should have answer the post, so I could accept it.

Comment: This is already a well known question though, check for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420761/laravel-5-2-not-reading-env-file , anyways, glad to have helped

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.2 not reading env file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420761/laravel-5-2-not-reading-env-file)