# why my .env always connects with old database?

Tags: php, laravel, phpdotenv

I am new to laravel. why does my laravel project keep connecting with the old database?

I tried to clear cache but nothing works for me `php artisan config: cache`

my env file is connected with the new database but shows error on terminal saying

> Unknown database 'admin'

Comment: Can you upload your .env file ?

Comment: check your config folder database.php

Comment: Correct command would be `php artisan config:clear` (without spaces after colon).

Comment: do you restart your server, after edit env file?

Comment: can you get answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel not reading changes to .env file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420761/laravel-not-reading-changes-to-env-file)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `php artisan config: cache`, it will create a **config.php** file under cache in your **bootstrap folder**.
So, If you change something in your **.env file**, it will not be updated in your cache **config.php** file.
Then, when you run `php artisan config:clear`, the new changes will be updated in your cache **config.php** file. That's why you are facing this problem.

To overcome this, try the following

1. delete the **config.php** file from *cache folder* inside *bootstrap folder*.
2. Run `composer update`.

I too faced issues like this, when I did the above steps, It solved.

Answer (score -1):

Hope your database credentials are correct in a `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=            // Your Database Name
DB_USERNAME=           // Your Database Username
DB_PASSWORD=          // Your Database Password
```

If All is correct then After completion of `.env` edit, You can clear the configuration cache with the following artisan command: `php artisan config:cache`

---

Also, check in `config/database.php`, Check that the old database name has not been used on it

Also, If you are using the PHP's default web server (eg. `php artisan serve`) you need to **restart your server** after changing your `.env` file values.