# .env file not updating in server?

Tags: php, laravel

After I uploaded my Laravel project in Cpanel I have to configure my env file according to my database.
I put database name, database user name and password also.
but after I save in the database and refresh my browser. it says

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `sliders`)

even though I have changed env file in server. but still showing me `root@localhost`.

Can't figure it out how to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel not reading changes to .env file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420761/laravel-not-reading-changes-to-env-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run `php artisan config:clear`

mostly because of .env being cached