# Can't see email configuration on artisan tinker

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-artisan, tinker

I have already set my email configuration on .env file but when i check from tinker is shows null value.

[image]

here is my env config

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=c57xxxx07f1
MAIL_PASSWORD=44****02fae
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

i cant send email any solution for this ??

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using? did you alter the `config/mail.php` file?

Comment: 5.8 no i didn't alter anything

Comment: i guess this wasn't a fresh 5.8 install and this was upgraded from previous versions? just trying to confirm why you are missing configuration keys that should be in the mail config for that version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find your `config/mail.php`

And put your env key inside.

```php
env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org')
```

First argument is your env key, second arg is the default value.

```php
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    ...
```

And clear config cache:

```php
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: @MuhammadSaad I think you env not working. Try to type ```ENV('MAIL_PORT')``` in tinker.

Comment: >>> ENV('MAIL_PORT')
=> "465"

Comment: Do you cache config before you set them?

Comment: its show everything in tinker when when i run config('mail')
its show nothing

Comment: @TsaiKoga in the screenshot they seem to be clearing the config cache before using tinker .. and `cache:clear` is for the cache store, not config cache or view cache or route cache

Comment: ya whenever i change config in my env file i clear my cache,config etc each and everything

Comment: @MuhammadSaad what about use double quotaion mark. like ```MAIL_PORT="465"```

Comment: i copied directly from terminal that y its showing in double quotation.

Comment: i think that config('mail')
is not picking the key value from env file thats y its showing null values in all column

Comment: @MuhammadSaad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420761/laravel-5-2-not-reading-env-file

Comment: @MuhammadSaad I have also said in my answer clear cache first.

Comment: @lagbox `cache:clear` do clear config cache. You can try it. It will clear the file in `boostrap/cache/config.php`

Comment: no, it does not `cache:clear` is for clearing the application cache/cache store .. `config:clear` clears the cached config file

Comment: it wont clear the config cache ... it is for flushing the cache store

Comment: @lagbox When I run `php artisan config:cache`, the `config.php` will generated in `bootstrap/cache`, and `php artisan cache:clear`, this file will be deleted.

Comment: it does not delete the config cache. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Cache/Console/ClearCommand.php that is the source code ... there is nothing in there that would delete any files in `bootstrap/cache`

Comment: @lagbox Sorry. My mistake. I run `php artisan config:clear` instead of `php artisan cache:clear` in my terminal. You are right. There are no `bootstrap/cache` in that source code.

Comment: its okay, just for some strange reason people only on Stack Overflow think that `cache:clear` is some magical command

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the cache after changes in your `env` file. Otherwise, your changes are not updated. So whenever you made changes need to clear cache and then after use tinker.

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan tinker

config('mail')
```

Comment: no, you don't need to clear the cache store ... the cache store has nothing to do with the config cache

Comment: @lagbox But when I have a try `cache:clear` command and then `tinker`. It is working on my local project.

Comment: the cache store has nothing to do with the configuration caching at all

Comment: @lagbox Ok understood.  Need to use `config:clear` command for configuration.

Answer (score 1):

after using config('email')
If you not get your .env email configuration then

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Then

```
php artisan tinker
```

```
config('mail')
```

get your result